# Beautiful soup class selector

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have two types of tables in a html page.

```
<table class="ui-table hp-formTable ui-table_type1 ui-table_sortable">
<table class="ui-table hp-raceRecords ui-table_type2">
```

I need to select only the first one. 
If I try something like this:

```
BSdata1 = BeautifulSoup(driver1.page_source, 'lxml')
Parameters = BSdata1.find_all('table',{'class':'ui-table hp-formTable ui-table_type1 ui-table_sortable'})
```

It keeps selecting both Tables. How can I select only the first one?
I am using Python3, BS4 and lxml parser on Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

The sample tables in your questions aren't properly formatted, but using css selectors this should work:

```
driver1.page_source = """
<doc>
<table class="ui-table hp-formTable ui-table_type1 ui-table_sortable">First Table</table>
<table class="ui-table hp-raceRecords ui-table_type2">Second Table</table>
</doc>
"""
BSdata1 = BeautifulSoup(driver1.page_source, 'lxml')
Parameters = BSdata1.select('table.ui-table.hp-formTable.ui-table_type1.ui-table_sortable')
Parameters
```

Output:

```
[<table class="ui-table hp-formTable ui-table_type1 ui-table_sortable">First Table</table>]
```